# Return Type Pthread Create Using C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I am trying to create a function that returns an object with certain type. The problem is that create thread does not accept it. Can somebody help me with the following code?

```
struct thread_args
 {
    Key *k;
    QNode *q;
    uint8_t USED_DIMENSION;
};

QLeafNode *st ;
  struct thread_args Structthread2;
     Structthread1.k=min;
     Structthread1.q=start;
      Structthread1.USED_DIMENSION=4 ;

pthread_create( &thread1, NULL,(void*)&FindLeafNode,  ((void *) &Structthread1));
pthread_join( thread1, (void**)st);

QLeafNode* FindLeafNode (Key *k, QNode * r, uint8_t USED_DIMENSION ){

}
```

Comment: The critical code isn't here. How is Structthread1 declared?

Comment: What does "create thread does not accept it" mean? Are you getting a compile error? A crash?

Comment: If I had to guess, it's the `void *` cast on `FindLeafNode`. (also the strange expectation that the code will do something reasonable when a function with 3 args receives one)

Comment: @AdamBatkin yeah it doesn't compile :((

Comment: [Relevant](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/15/58973.aspx), even though the examples are windows-related, the same logic applies.

Comment: Right, I figured. But rather than complaining that it doesn't compile, it is vastly more helpful if you actually post the compiler error message instead of making us guess at what could be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, your thread function is not correctly defined. Only functions of the form:

```
void* function_name(void* param)
```

can be passed to `pthread_create`.

Now, in order to return a pointer to something from this function, you need two pthread functions:

```
pthread_exit(void *value_ptr);
```

Call this inside the thread function to return a value through `value_ptr` and

```
pthread_join(pthread_t thread, void **value_ptr);
```

Call this inside the parent thread to wait for the termination of the child with handle `thread` and retrieve the value returned by `pthread_exit` in `value_ptr`.

So your code should look something like:

```
struct thread_args
 {
    Key *k;
    QNode *q;
    uint8_t USED_DIMENSION;
};

QLeafNode *st ;
struct thread_args Structthread1;
Structthread1.k=min;
Structthread1.q=start;
Structthread1.USED_DIMENSION=4 ;

pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, FindLeafNode,  ((void *) &Structthread1));
pthread_join(thread1, (void**)st);

...

void* FindLeafNode (void* param) {
    struct thread_args* value = (struct thread_args*) param;
    // use value for computations
    QLeafNode* result = ... // allocate result with new / malloc
    pthread_exit((void*)result);
}
```

Comment: Technically, I believe you're supposed to pass `&FindLeafNode` instead of `FindLeafNode`.

Comment: @Hurkyl: Not as far as I know. I actually used pthreads recently and it works with just `FindLeafNode`.

Comment: QuadTree.cc:332: error: argument of type ‘void* (QuadTree::)(void*)’ does not match ‘void* (*)(void*)’

Comment: So `FindLeafNode` is a member of `QuadTree`? Then we may have a problem, because a pointer to a function is not the same as a pointer to a member. See this discussion for example: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.6. Is it possible the make `FindLeafNode` static?

Comment: thnx @Tudor for your great explanation however I think the error is appearing because we have a problem with the third parameter to the create Pthread!

Comment: @shaklasah: See my previous comment. It's not really possible to pass a class method to `pthread_create`.

Comment: +1, btw, you can also return a value from the thread function instead of calling `pthread_exit`.

Answer (score 0):

return a heap-allocated pointer to [so use `new` to allocate it] your new object (allocated in the thread, and perhaps later freed in the "parent" thread joining it, i.e. using the result).

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't compile for pthread_create in the first place :((

Comment: How did you compile it (which system, which compiler, which compiler options), what exact source code did you compile, and what exact error message did you got?

Comment: QuadTree.cc:332: error: ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function.  Say ‘&QuadTree::FindLeafNode’

Comment: QuadTree.cc:332: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘void* (*)(void*)’

Comment: `pthread_create` requires a routine pointer (e.g. the name of a routine) as its 3<sup>rd</sup> argument. If `FindLeafNode` is a function, just pass its name.